# Android: How to get company domain name from code

Tags: android

I know I have set a company domain when I created the project, but how can I get the domain name as a String from code? This is useful because I'm writing a library project and one of the features requires to collect apps(apps using my library)'s company domains.

I did set "Company Domain" when I create a new project with Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

I understand I can get the package name and/or application ID, but that's not what I want. I want to get the "Company Domain" as mentioned above (maybe it's not required during project creation, but if it is set, can I get it from code?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have set a company domain when I created the project

No, you set a package name/application ID when creating the project. While using a reverse domain name is a typical approach for getting a likely-to-be-unique application ID, it is not a requirement.

> how can I get the domain name as a String from code?

You are welcome to call `getPackageName()` on a `Context` to retrieve the application ID associated with the application. Again, this may or may not have any resemblance to a domain name. There is no requirement that Android developers provide a domain name as part of their apps.

> one of the feature requires to collect apps(apps using my library)'s company domains

I trust that you will only do this with full disclosure to the developers using the library.

> I did set "Company Domain" when I create a new project with Android Studio

That is in Android Studio. That is not in Android. That field is only used to suggest an application ID. It is not stored as part of your project, and it is not available at runtime.

> I want to get the the "Company Domain" as mentioned above

Then you will need to have some sort of API in your library where developers supply a domain name.

> but if it is set, can I get it from code?

No.

Comment: I updated my question, just let you know you didn't answer my question if you care

Comment: @yongsunCN: Yes, I did answer your question. I have now updated my answer based upon your updated question.

Comment: Your new edit answered my question, not the original one, and thanks. It's good to make these things clear because I believe there are people like me don't know this detail before.